# Free tier ended today Nov 28 and Heroku site deleted today

Tags: swift, heroku

My heroku site has been deleted because I did not switch to the paid plan.  I just switched to Eco Dyno's will my site automatically come back or do I need to rebuild? Note: using Heroku platform for Nightscout

I upgraded to a paid Eco Dyno's site

Comment: Did you scale up at least one `web` dyno?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ask heroku support.
[how to ask heroku support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8duH.png)